# why `wget` can not get redirection for certain website?

Tags: wget, redirect

`wget` hangs there while it accesses the following website. But when I use a browser to access it, it will be redirected to https://nyulangone.org. Does anybody know why wget can not get redirected in this case? Thanks.

```
$ wget http://nyumc.org
--2018-02-20 20:27:05--  http://nyumc.org/
Resolving nyumc.org (nyumc.org)... 216.165.125.106
Connecting to nyumc.org (nyumc.org)|216.165.125.106|:80...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used wget on the site you mentioned, this is what I get:

```
--2018-02-21 21:16:38--  http://www.nyumc.org/
Resolving www.nyumc.org (www.nyumc.org)... 216.165.125.112
Connecting to www.nyumc.org (www.nyumc.org)|216.165.125.112|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 179 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html               100%[==================================>]     179  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-02-21 21:16:38 (8.16 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [179/179]
```

In the `index.html` file, which bears the logo of NYU Langone Medical Center, it says: "*The following URL has been rejected for security concerns. If you believe you have received this message in error, please summit an incident with our helpdesk at 212-263-6868*..." So, it may not redirect because the website can detect that you are a bot and not a browser. You could attempt to change the user agent string and other HTTP headers to avoid detection, but I'm not sure why you wouldn't just turn wget on https://nyulangone.org. Judging from information on archive.org, nyumc.org has been redirecting to other sites for at least the last 5 years. It was redirecting to http://www.med.nyu.edu until 2016, at which point it started redirecting to https://www.nyulangone.org.

I hope that helps.